# Button click does not change anything in database c#

Tags: c#, ms-access

Button click when workorder exist to update the datatable does not change anything in the datatable but when the workorder does not exist it will insert data into the datatable. Does anyone know where i gone wrong? I have changed the update statement from my other post([Syntax error in update using C# inputting data into an existing row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59149357/syntax-error-in-update-using-c-sharp-inputting-data-into-an-existing-row/)) when this problem(button click dont change anything) appears

```
private void save_care_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox2.Text=="")
            MessageBox.Show("No data, Please scan workorder");
        else
        {

                //Checking if workorder exist in database
                connection.Open();
                OleDbCommand checkrecord = new OleDbCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [c# barcode] WHERE ([Workorder] = @workorder)", connection);
                checkrecord.Parameters.AddWithValue("@workorder", textBox2.Text);
                int recordexist = (int)checkrecord.ExecuteScalar();
                if (recordexist > 0)
                {
                    //add data if it exist
                    string cmdText = "UPDATE [c# barcode] SET [Close from care] =@Close,[Name care] =@name WHERE[Workorder] = @workorder"; ; 
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, connection))
                {

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@workorder", textBox2.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Close", DateTime.Now.ToString("d/M/yyyy"));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", label4.Text);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    textBox2.Clear();
                    connection.Close();
                }
                    connection.Close();
                }


                else
                {
                    //inserting workorder if it does not exist
                    string cmdText = "INSERT INTO [c# barcode] ([Workorder],[Close from care],[Name care]) VALUES (@workorder,@Close,@name)";
                    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, connection))
                    {

                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@workorder", textBox2.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Close", DateTime.Now.ToString("d/M/yyyy"));
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", label4.Text);

                        if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
                        {
                            textBox2.Clear();
                            MessageBox.Show("Insert succesful, workorder has not been handedover, Please Check");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            textBox2.Clear();
                            MessageBox.Show("Please rescan");
                            connection.Close();
                        }
                        connection.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: MS Access uses positional parameter, not named parameters (the name doesn't count, only its position is considered. You could use `?` instead of a name). Your parameters are inserted in the wrong order. You should also make sure that all fields you're specifying have a matching parameter.

Comment: oh my. Thanks it works!

Answer (score 0):

string cmdText = "UPDATE [c# barcode] SET [Close from care] =@Close,[Name care] =@name WHERE[Workorder] = @workorder"; ;

First check the double semicolon at this string doesn't the compiler complain?